# Azure SQL Database Manipulation

Tags: python, sql, azure, azure-database-mysql

Is it possible to create a table in an Azure sql database using Python? I am pulling a list of things from an API and then want to push them to a table in my Azure sql db but can not find a tutorial or guide on how to do so. Googling for it led me to tutorials on how to pull data from my db. Thanks

Comment: [Azure SQL Database libraries for Python | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/sql?view=azure-python)
 - 
[Use Python to query a database - Azure SQL Database & SQL Managed Instance | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?tabs=windows)

Comment: Hi Zlot, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonYue I was looking how to create a table not a database.

Comment: Just replace the query statements with "Create table...".

Comment: Hello @Zlot, did you solve the problem? If you have any concerns, please let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Azure SQL database, you could follow the Azure official tutorial which @ Mohamed Elrashid provided for you: [Azure SQL Database libraries for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/sql?view=azure-python):

Example:

Create a SQL Database resource and restrict access to a range of IP addresses using a firewall rule.

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.sql import SqlManagementClient

RESOURCE_GROUP = 'YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME'
LOCATION = 'eastus'  # example Azure availability zone, should match resource group
SQL_SERVER = 'yourvirtualsqlserver'
SQL_DB = 'YOUR_SQLDB_NAME'
USERNAME = 'YOUR_USERNAME'
PASSWORD = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'

# create resource client
resource_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ResourceManagementClient)
# create resource group
resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP, {'location': LOCATION})

sql_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(SqlManagementClient)

# Create a SQL server
server = sql_client.servers.create_or_update(
    RESOURCE_GROUP,
    SQL_SERVER,
    {
        'location': LOCATION,
        'version': '12.0', # Required for create
        'administrator_login': USERNAME, # Required for create
        'administrator_login_password': PASSWORD # Required for create
    }
)

# Create a SQL database in the Basic tier
database = sql_client.databases.create_or_update(
    RESOURCE_GROUP,
    SQL_SERVER,
    SQL_DB,
    {
        'location': LOCATION,
        'collation': 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
        'create_mode': 'default',
        'requested_service_objective_name': 'Basic'
    }
)

# Open access to this server for IPs
firewall_rule = sql_client.firewall_rules.create_or_update(
    RESOURCE_GROUP,
    SQL_DB,
    "firewall_rule_name_123.123.123.123",
    "123.123.123.123", # Start ip range
    "167.220.0.235"  # End ip range
)
```

If you are using Azure Database for MySQL, please ref this Azure tutorial [Python + Azure Database for MySQL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-mysql/python-azure-database-for-mysql/ba-p/841926).

Azure Database for MySQL and Python can be used together for data analysis – MySQL as database engine and Python as statistical tool. When dealing with large datasets that potentially exceed the memory of your machine it is recommended to push the data into database engine, where you can query the data in smaller digestible chunks.

In this article we will learn how to use Python to perform the following tasks:

- Create Azure Database for MySQL using [azure python sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python)

Hope this helps.